# Java HashSet to array

Tags: java, arrays, set, hashset

I'm trying to convert a HashSet to an Array of Doubles. Yes I have a main method and class defined, I've just included what I've imported as well as the code for this specific function.

This is the Error that shows up:

```
Ass10.java:148: error: no suitable method found for toArray(double[])
                rtrn = s.toArray(rtrn);
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;


public static double[] negated(double[] a) {
        Set<Double> s = new HashSet<Double>();
        for(double x : a) {
            s.add(x);
        } for(double x : s) {
            if(s.contains(-x) == false) {
                s.remove(x);
            }
        }
        double[] rtrn = new double[s.size()];
        rtrn = s.toArray(rtrn);
        return rtrn;
        }
```

Comment: Essentially there is no way to case a double[] to a Double[] like there is a double to a Double and visa versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a primitive array in this scenario, as there's no auto-boxing for arrays in Java. Use a `Double[]` for that to work.

Answer (score 1):

Java collections works with reference type. The function `Collection.toArray(T[] a)` has a signature of generic reference type. So you will need to pass a reference type array instead of primitive array. The corresponding reference type of primitive type `double` is `Double`.

```
Double[] rtrn = new Double[s.size()];
rtrn = s.toArray(rtrn);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a compile time error, right? Try using Double[] instead of double[].